# Dynamic dropdowns using DD4T

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, content-manager

On our website we want to show three Dropdowns State, City and Area.  Behavior of these dropdowns is as given below.

- State dropdown will be populated on page load.
- On selection of state cities under selected state will be populated
  in city dropdown.
- On selection of city Areas under that city will be populated in area
  dropdown

We created category called State under that we created all states as keyword.  Under each state keyword we created sub/child keyword as City, and under each city keyword we created child/sub keyword as area.

Using below Java DD4T code we are able to access all States, but we are not able to get child/subkeywords for City can anyone guide us?

```
TaxonomyFactory tx = new TaxonomyFactory(); 
    com.tridion.taxonomies.Keyword keyss = tx.getTaxonomyKeywords("tcm:43-605-512");
    com.tridion.taxonomies.Keyword keysq = tx.getTaxonomyKeywords("tcm:43-24451-1024");

keysq is displayed as null here.
```

Comment: Have you published the Category since adding the sub-keywords?